# Updating the quantity if item already exists in cart

Tags: php, html, session, shopping-cart

Hi all so I managed to get the subtotal of all items in my cart thankyou to stack overflow user KyleK. The last functionality that im having problems with is adding 1 to the quantity of  a particular item in the cart if that item already exits. At the minute if I click add to basket twice then the same item is listed twice. Instead it would be great to have the item listed once with the quantity of two if this makes sense.

Thankyou in advance.

My code is located here at stack overflow.

[My Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17129590/i-need-help-getting-the-grand-total-of-a-simple-php-cart-using-sessions)

Comment: please do not self dupe your post

Comment: I cannot understand why this question is a possible duplicate when im not using a MYSQL database and that question to me is entirely different to the one im asking. And no were in my question mentions a "model circus store"

Comment: sorry its my mistake .... its possible duplicate of [I need help getting the grand total of a simple php cart using sessions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17129590/i-need-help-getting-the-grand-total-of-a-simple-php-cart-using-sessions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the chunk of code that you would need to modify in order to do what you want:

```
//Add an item only if we have the threee required pices of information: name, price, qty
if (isset($_GET['add']) && isset($_GET['price']) && isset($_GET['qty'])){
        //Adding an Item
        //Store it in a Array
        $ITEM = array(
                //Item name            
                'name' => $_GET['add'],
                //Item Price
                'price' => $_GET['price'],
                //Qty wanted of item
                'qty' => $_GET['qty']          
                );

        //Add this item to the shopping cart
        $_SESSION['SHOPPING_CART'][] =  $ITEM;
        //Clear the URL variables
        header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
}
```

If you click "add" twice, you are simply running this bit of code twice. If you want to have a "smart" cart, you'll need to modify this portion of code to include a check of the existing cart items. If the passed in item already exists, increment the quantity value for that item. If it doesn't exist, add it to the cart as a new item.

```
$addItem = $_GET['add'];

$itemExists = checkCartForItem($addItem, $_SESSION['SHOPPING_CART']);

if ($itemExists){
     // item exists - increment quantity value by 1
     $_SESSION['SHOPPING_CART'][$itemExists]['qty']++;
} else {
     // item does not exist - create new item and add to cart
     ...
}

// Then, add this code somewhere toward the top of your code before your 'if' block
function checkCartForItem($addItem, $cartItems) {
     if (is_array($cartItems)){
          foreach($cartItems as $key => $item) {
              if($item['name'] === $addItem)
                  return $key;
          }
     }
     return false;
}
```